# Swift 5: Is there a default implementation of creationDate and lastEditDate for CoreData Entities?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data

I am working with `CoreData` and am just implementing `creationDate` and `lastEditDate` properties for all my entities.

---

Are there default implementations for this by `CoreData` that would save this work? I can't find anything on this. Thanks for your help!

Comment: No, there are no default implementations. Set `creationDate` in `awakeFromInsert`. And `lastEditDate` depends on your definition of *edit*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `awakeFromInsert` and `willSave`. By extending your entity

```
extension YourEntity{
    public override func awakeFromInsert() {
        if creationDate == nil{
            self.creationDate = Date()
        }
        super.awakeFromInsert()
    }
    
    public override func willSave() {
        self.lastEditDate = Date()
        super.willSave()
    }
}
```

Comment: That `awakeFromInsert` could be a problem if you sync data between devices or if you use nested contexts. I know it sounds strange but you should probably check whether `creationDate` is nil before setting its value there.